# Telerik Reports Table view duplicated

Tags: c#, telerik, telerik-reporting

Hi I an using the Telerik Report view to generate a report.

All good, I have mapped the data to my data source and the report looks great in the design view.

[image]

But when I view it in the Preview pane it duplicates the table X times the number of the rows i have returned.

[image]
Anyone know why this is ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this issue when building a report page that had textboxes and a table. The textboxes took their values from `ReportParameters` and the table was using an `objectDataSource`.

The problem was that I had my `objectDataSource` assigned to the `DataSource` of both the page itself and the table.

To fix the issue I just removed the `objectDataSource` from the page.

Answer (score 1):

You have duplicate Table cause your datasource is bound to the page item.

So lets be quick. 2 solutions , choose one!

1. Use the gui to apply filter on the table.

   Filter on a unique data. like this :

   ```
   =Fields.myField_ID_XYZ     =    =ReportItem.DataObject.myField_ID_XYZ
   ```
2. In code behind :

   ```
   this.table2.Filters.Add(    
       new Telerik.Reporting.Filter(
           "= Fields.myField_ID_XYZ"
           , Telerik.Reporting.FilterOperator.Equal
           , "=ReportItem.DataObject.myField_ID_XYZ"    
        ));
   ```

This will prevent the duplication of the table.

Filtering it on the `ReportItem.DataObject.myField_ID_XYZ`, the current row of the `DetailSection`.